# Is it okay to set these out on our table at LinuxFest Northwest?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, promote, copyright

I'll be helping out at the [Ubuntu Washington LoCo Team](http://loco.ubuntu.com/teams/ubuntu-washington) table at [LinuxFest Northwest](http://linuxfestnorthwest.org/) this weekend, and I thought it might be a good opportunity to spread the word about Ask Ubuntu. Is it okay to get these printed and set them out for visitors?

Sheet 1, front:
[image: Sheet 1, front]

Sheet 1, back:
[image: Sheet 1, back]

Sheet 2, front:
[image: Sheet 2, front]

Sheet 2, back:
[image: Sheet 2, back]

I have posted the [source files](http://spreadubuntu.org/en/material/brochure/ask-ubuntu-handouts) and a [printable PDF](http://spreadubuntu.org/files/huge/askubuntu-handouts-combined.pdf) on SpreadUbuntu.

Comment: Dude these look great! If you can post the source so other people can use them it'd be awesome!

Comment: Fabulous job @ændrük The source for these would be great (I would practically carry these around like business cards, tbh)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Is it okay to set them out?** Yes, definitely.

**Is it okay for you to have them printed?** If you insist… but Stack Exchange is happy to do it.

If there's enough time (*this* weekend?), you can email a PDF to me at `dori (at) stackexchange`, and I can have the amazing Amanda find a printer near you where you can pick them up.

We're always happy to see people promoting their sites, and want to make it as easy as possible for you to do so.

For anyone reading this in the future: want some help with site promotion? Just let us know what we can do (and thanks)!

---

***Followup***:

Amanda worked with the printer @ændrük recommended, and he'll be able to pick them up this afternoon (you see why I said she was amazing?).

ændrük, let us know in enough time, and we'll see about helping to [sponsor the conference](http://linuxfestnorthwest.org/sponsors) next year. But most importantly, thanks *so* much for helping to make this happen.

I *love* it when a plan comes together!